# Python Matplotlib legend colors don't work properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I created a scatter plot with Python Matplotlib/Seaborn. The code looks like follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="Date", y="Time", hue="Sender", palette=["#329335", "#C23D3D"])
```

There's more code but it doesn't change anything with the legend or the colors. Now if I show this plot I get the default  legend:

[image]

So far everything works fine. The legend has a header which comes from the `hue` argument. I don't want the header so I added `ax.legend()` which only displays the elements from `"Sender"`, so it also works fine. Now I want to change the labels in the legend which should work through `ax.legend(labels = ["Name 1", "Name 2"]`. However now there is an issue with the label colors:

[image]

The labels are correct but instead of a green and a red circle next to the labels, the first label has a small green dot and the second one the normal green circle which should be by "Name 2" though.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that little gree none dot is the part of the background btw. it seems there is no dot for name 1

Comment: It's actually not, if I move the legend out of the box, it's also there.

Comment: Try adding title="Sender" in the ax.legend it should do the trick

Comment: @tanglef It doesn't work that way and also that's the reason I used ax.legend() in the first place to get rid of the title :D

Comment: @JohanC thank you. this works fine. Do you mind me asking another small question? Do you know how I can switch the order of the labels?

Comment: Does the updated answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly calling `get_legend_handles_labels()` and using these for legend does the job. For some unknown reason, seaborn creates 3 `PathCollection`s. One with zero elements and a label starting with an underscore. Followed by two ordinary `PathCollection`s, one for each hue value. Labels starting with underscore are automatically skipped from the legend. If you just call `ax.legend(labels=['Name 1', 'Name 2'])`, the first dummy collection gets a real label (`Name 1`), and the second collection (the first "normal" collection) gets label `Name 2`.

To reverse the order of the labels, just reverse both the handles and the labels lists: `ax.legend(handles=handles[::-1], labels=['Name 2', 'Name 1'])`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

N = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(0, 100, N),
                   'y': np.random.uniform(0, 50, N),
                   'Sender': np.random.choice(['green-eyed', 'red-eyed'], N)})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="Sender", palette=["#329335", "#C23D3D"], ax=ax)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[::-1], labels=['Name 2', 'Name 1'])
plt.show()
```